# Why is my code stuck on CircularProgressIndicator()

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, rest, http

```
import 'package:app/logic/models/http.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/myhomepage.dart';
import 'logic/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  Http http = Http();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Stream.fromFuture(
        http.makeUserGetRequest(),
      ),
      builder: (context, response) {
        if (!response.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (response.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('${response.error}'),
          );
        } else {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              Provider<List<User>?>.value(value: response.data),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Rest Api',
              theme: ThemeData(
                brightness: Brightness.dark,
                primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
              ),
              home: const MyHomePage(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my main and the below code is http file import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
import 'dart:convert';
import './user.dart';
import '../BO/bo.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Http {
  //localhost || 10.0.2.2 (mysql for Android Emulator)
  final url = 'localhost:8000/';
  final users = 'users/';
  final headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
  Http();

  Future<List<User>> makeUserGetRequest() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$url$users'));
    List<User> result = List<User>.from(
      json.decode(response.body).map((json) => User.fromJson(json)),
    );
    result.sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
    print(getStatusCode(response.statusCode));
    return result;
  }

  makeUserPostRequest(User user) async {
    String body = json.encode(user.toJson());
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('$url$users'),
      headers: headers,
      encoding: encoding,
      body: body,
    );
    print((response.body));
    print(
        'response status ${response.statusCode} => ${getStatusCode(response.statusCode)}');
  }

  makeUserPutRequest(User user) async {
    String body = json.encode(user.toJson());
    http.Response response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$url$users${user.id}'),
        headers: headers, encoding: encoding, body: body);
    print((response.body));
    print(
        'response status ${response.statusCode} => ${getStatusCode(response.statusCode)}');
  }

  makeUserDeleteRequest(User user) async {
    http.Response response =
        .
3await http.delete(Uri.parse('$url$users${user.id}'), headers: headers);
    print((response.body));
    print(
        'response status ${response.statusCode} => ${getStatusCode(response.statusCode)}');
  }
}
```

I am trying to make restful api using node.js as server, mysql as database and flutter as frontend.
I have checked my backend using Postman and it is working fine but once I try to run the app on either emulator or physical device I am just getting a Circular Progress Indicator Widget.
What is wrong and how do I solve this? Please do tell. I am new to API and Backend.

Comment: try to debug/print `response.data`, it might not having the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to flip the logic when dealing with StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder, so that in any situation that is not caught it is displaying a progress indicator.

```
...
Widget build(BuiildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Stream.formFuture(http.makeUserGetRequest(),),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  )
}
```

Also why are converting a future to a stream, when a FutureBuilder exists?

```
...
Widget build(BuiildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: http.makeUserGetRequest(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  )
}
```